# Connecting to an SQL database over the internet using C#

Tags: c#, sql, bash, oracle, ssh

I'm currently doing an assignment where I want my program to be able to read and update a database. The database itself runs on oracle and was provided by my university (I have my own schema I believe?)

Right now I can connect via SSH using programs such as teraterm or putty, once I log in it takes me to an interactive menu which allows me to select a few various options. One of which is shell. Once I select that I am able to use bash commands to log into the SQL section and use these:

```
bash$ export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/client/11.2.0
bash$ export TWO_TASK=SSID
bash$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus
```

to connect to the SQL database. Easy.

However, I want to be able to do that through my program and it is proving difficult for me. I am using [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) and can connect via SSH seemingly well. The problem is I cannot access the SQL section. When I run the commands the first two work correctly I believe, but the last one does not. It seems to not be able to see the anything past $ORACLE_HOME. When I "echo $ORACLE_HOME /*" it even tells me that /bin is a folder:

```
/bin /boot /dev /etc /export /hey.php /home /lib /lib64 /local /lost+found /media /misc 
/mnt /opt /proc /root /sbin /selinux /srv /stage /sys /tmp /usr /var
```

But instead, when I run the last line of code I get the error message:

```
Error = "bash: /bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory\n"
```

I'm not sure whether there is an easier way of accessing the SQL stuff... But I am very close using SSH.NET but I just can't see why I can't open the SQL section like I can in putty or teraterm...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

My actual C# code is this:

```
//Connection information
string user = "SSHusername";
string pass = "password";
string host = "address";

//Set up the SSH connection
using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
{

    //Start the connection
    client.Connect();
    var output = client.RunCommand("export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/client/11.2.0");
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
    output = client.RunCommand("export TWO_TASK=SSID");
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
    output = client.RunCommand("$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus");
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
    output = client.RunCommand("username");
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
    output = client.RunCommand("password");
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
    output = client.RunCommand("SELECT * FROM users;");
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);

    client.Disconnect();
    Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your third `RunCommand` call doesn't pick up the environment variables set by the first two calls. Did you check whether each `RunCommand` call opens a new shell, thus resetting the environment variables ?

Answer (score 0):

1.I suggest you use native C# package for connect Oracle. You will get wrong format of output.

2. I see your variable is not work. Because SQLPLUS client should be under 
   $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus. But your code show /bin/sqlplus. Means $ORACE_HOME not work.
3. You can directly change code and run directly sqlplus like /opt/oracle/product/client/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus user/pass@SSID
4. You can set some script on remote oracle server and get result over that or upload script from C# host to remote each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SSH.NET library, using a Shell instead of separate Commands should work - something like (untested):

```
 using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass)) {
            client.Connect();
            client.CreateCommand("export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/client/11.2.0").Execute();
            client.CreateCommand("export TWO_TASK=SSID").Execute();
            client.CreateCommand("$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus").Execute());
            ...
            client.Disconnect();
  }
```

Original source code found at [SSH.NET example](https://gist.github.com/piccaso/d963331dcbf20611b094)